# Lua Semicolon Conventions

Tags: lua, conventions

I was wondering if there is a general convention for the usage of semicolons in Lua, and if so, where/why should I use them? I come from a programming background, so ending statements with a semicolon seems intuitively correct. However I was concerned as to why they are `"optional"` when its generally accepted that semicolons end statements in other programming languages. Perhaps there is some benefit?

For example: From the [lua programming guide](http://www.lua.org/pil/1.1.html), these are all acceptable, equivalent, and syntactically accurate:

```
a = 1
b = a*2

a = 1;
b = a*2;

a = 1 ; b = a*2

a = 1   b = a*2    -- ugly, but valid
```

The author also mentions: `Usually, I use semicolons only to separate two or more statements written in the same line, but this is just a convention.`

Is this generally accepted by the Lua community, or is there another way that is preferred by most? Or is it as simple as my personal preference?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Semi-colons in Lua are generally only required when writing multiple statements on a line.

So for example:

```
local a,b=1,2; print(a+b)
```

Alternatively written as:

```
local a,b=1,2
print(a+b)
```

Off the top of my head, I can't remember any other time in Lua where I *had* to use a semi-colon.

Edit: looking in the lua 5.2 reference I see one other common place where you'd need to use semi-colons to avoid ambiguity - where you have a simple statement followed by a function call or parens to group a compound statement. here is the manual example located [here](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#3.3):

```
--[[ Function calls and assignments can start with an open parenthesis. This 
possibility leads to an ambiguity in the Lua grammar. Consider the 
following fragment: ]]

a = b + c
(print or io.write)('done')

-- The grammar could see it in two ways:

a = b + c(print or io.write)('done')

a = b + c; (print or io.write)('done')
```

Comment: Actually, `local a,b=1,2 print(a+b)` is valid Lua and does what you would expect. You only need semicolons to prevent ambiguity. Same goes for spaces by the way. So this works too `print(1)print(2)`

Answer (score 0):

in local variable and function definition. Here I compare two quite similar sample codes to illustrate my point of view.

```
local f;  f = function() function-body end

local f = function() function-body end
```

These two functions can return different results when the function-body section contains reference to variable "f".

Comment: This is why `local function f` is valid, but I don't see how this answer pertains to the question at hand.

Answer (score 0):

**Many programming languages (including Lua) that do not require semicolons have a convention to not use them, except for separating multiple statements on the same line**.

Javascript is an important exception, which generally uses semicolons by convention.

Kotlin is also technically an exception. The [Kotlin Documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coding-conventions.html) say not only not to use semicolons on non-batched statements, but also to

> Omit semicolons whenever possible.

Answer (score -1):

For having more than one thing on a line, for example:

```
c=5
a=1+c
print(a) -- 6
```

could be shortened to:

```
c=5; a=1+c; print(a) -- 6
```

also worth noting that if you're used to Javascript, or something like that, where you have to end a line in a semicolon, and you're especially used to writing that, then this means that you won't have to remove that semicolon, and trust me, i'm used to Javascript too, and I really, really forget that you don't need the semicolon, every time I write a new line!

Comment: Semicolons are optional in JavaScript as well. Contrary to Lua, most people are writing them anyway by convention. But the so-called “StandardJS” style guide (https://standardjs.com/) argues to omit them, just like in Lua.

Comment: @LaurensHolst everything you said is correct, but that StandardJS thing is definitely wrong. Their argument is "At the end of the day, just pick something", and they don't seem to know that _the well-ingrained Javascript convention is to use semicolons_.

Comment: @TheRealSuicune Do you realize that although program won't die, you're effectively breaking the rules? Have you ever tried writing `<!-- comment` instead of `// comment`? They both work, but it breaks the conventions, and thus confuses people.

Comment: @Sapphire_Brick Actually the StandardJS seems to imply that it prefers no semicolons.  For example, on their web page they describe the "semistandard" with the following language: "Semistandard:  Same as standard with semicolons (if you must)".  This kind of language sends the message that the "standard" is without semicolons, and if you use semicolons then you're using the "semistandard".  Also the "(if you must)" comment implies that it is preferred that the "semistandard" (and thus the use of semicolons) is not the first choice preferred style.

Answer (score -1):

In local variable definitions, we get ambiguous results from time to time:

```
local a, b = string.find("hello world", "hello") --> a = nil, b = nil
```

while sometimes a and b are assigned the right values 7 and 11.

So I found no choice but to follow one of these two approaches:

1. `local a, b; a, b = string.find("hello world", "hello") --> a, b = 7, 11`
2. `local a, b
   a, b = string.find("hello world", "hello") --> a, b = 7, 11`

Comment: This answer is incorrect. First, the correct values for `find` are 1, 5. Second, the first statement [puts those values into `a` and `b` just fine](https://www.ideone.com/yYRc3R).